# How to get and set element position in javascript

Tags: javascript, position

all

I'm confused about the position of an element. Let me start by how to get/set the left propety of an element.

First, there is one way to set the element left position, use element.style.left. I copy the definition from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp to below:

1. For absolutely positioned elements, the left property sets the left edge of an element to a unit to the left/right of the left edge of  its **containing element**.
2. For relatively positioned elements, the left property sets the left edge of an element to a unit to the left/right to its **normal position**.

so my questions are:

1. In definition 1, is the containing element equal to the element.parentNode?
2. In definition 2, how can I get the element's normal position?

Second, we can get the left position through element.offsetLeft. If I try this way, I should know which element is the element's offsetParent. I also copy the definition which I goole from internet below:

- The offsetParent property refers to the nearest positioned
  (non-static) ancestor element. If there is no such element,
  offsetParent will refer to the body element

And I write a test Html file and try to get the offsetParent.

```
    <div id="div_1">
        <p id="p_1">
            Lorum ipsum...
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="div_2" style="position: relative;">
        <p id="p_2">
            Lorum ipsum...
        </p>
    </div>
    <table id="table_1">
        <th>
        <tr>
            <td id="td_1">Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr></th>
    </table>
```

The offsetParent of element p_1 is body, and the offsetParent of element p_2 is div_2, so far, everything's good. But I try to get the  offsetParent of element td_1, the result is table_1, not body. Why? Accroding to the definition, I think it shoud be doby, because there is no nearest positioned (non-static) ancestor element.

Hi, claustrofob, thanks for your replay, I think you have answered parts of my question, about why the td's offsetParent is table. But accroding to your another answer about style.left, I do not agree. I writed a new test file, below is the fragment:

```
    <div id="div_2" style="border:2px solid red; width: 500; height: 300;position: relative;">
        <div  id="div_3" style="border:2px solid blue;left:100px; width: 300; height: 100;">
            <p id="p_2" style="position: relative;left: 30px">
                Lorum ipsum...
            </p>                
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var p_2 = document.getElementById('p_2');
        document.write("<div>The position property of Element p_2 is "+ p_2.style.position +"</div>")
        document.write("<div>The style.left of Element p_2 is "+ p_2.style.left +"</div>")
        document.write("<div>The offsetParent of Element p_2 is "+ p_2.offsetParent.id +"</div>")
        document.write("<div>The offsetLeft of Element p_2 is "+ p_2.offsetLeft +"</div>")
        document.write("<br/>")
        var div_3 = document.getElementById('div_3');
        document.write("<div>The position property of Element div_3 is "+ (div_3.style.position ? div_3.style.position : 'not defined') +"</div>")
        document.write("<div>The style.left of Element div_3 is "+ div_3.style.left +"</div>")
        document.write("<div>The offsetParent of Element div_3 is "+ div_3.offsetParent.id +"</div>")
        document.write("<div>The offsetLeft of Element div_3 is "+ div_3.offsetLeft +"</div>")          
    </script>
```

The outPut is:

The position property of Element p_2 is relative

The style.left of Element p_2 is 30px

The offsetParent of Element p_2 is div_2

The offsetLeft of Element p_2 is 30

The position property of Element div_3 is not defined

The style.left of Element div_3 is 100px

The offsetParent of Element div_3 is div_2

The offsetLeft of Element div_3 is 0

If you focus on the output about element div_3, you can find obviously the style.left does no equal to the distance from element to element.offsetParent.

Comment: Don't trust w3schools. Why? [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: definition 1 is right. for def 2... you can use jquer to set position which works perfectly for cross browsers... if you do not want to use jquery then check this link... it has been explained in detail... http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For relatively positioned elements top/left coordinates define offset from its normal position. It means that the element with the next style properties:

```
{
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

will stay at its original position. Changing top/left will move the element from that position.

For absolutely positioned elements top/left defines the offset from the closest parent with relative or absolute position. You can think of it like absolutely or relatively positioned element defines a new point of origin for it's child elements. The top level point of origin is your body element.

Comment: So, for absolutely positioned elements, the container element is the element.parentNode, is it right?

Comment: @user2155362 If under _container element_ you mean the parent element in the DOM tree so the answer is yes. Positioned elements doesn't change their position in DOM tree. But if you mean the closest ancestor to what it is relatively positioned then look the the `element.offsetParent`

Comment: Hi, claustrofob, thanks for your replay. I think you have answered my second question about how to calculate the normal position. But I still confused about the concept about container element(in question 1) and offsetParent. It is obviously offsetParent does not equal to element.parentNode, and the offsetLeft means the distance from element to it's offsetParent, so I think is the style.left means the distance from element to element.parentNode?

Comment: And would you like to tell me how the browser calculate the offsetParent ? Because accroding to my test result, the offsetParent property does not always refer to the nearest positioned (non-static) ancestor element

Comment: style.left is the distance to offsetParent. Would you mind to share your test on jsFiddle?

Comment: I pasted the html fragment in the article, the test result is The offsetParent of element p_1 is body,offsetParent of element p_2 is div_2, offsetParent of element td_1, the result is table_1. The aim of test is try to find out which is the offsetParent of an element.

Comment: By default table cells are aligned relatively to table. That's why `td.offsetParent = table`. If you pull out td out of the flow with `position: absolute` you will get `offsetParent = body`.

Comment: Hi, claustrofob, I modify my article and paste a new test file fragement, It's obviously style.left does not equal to distance from element to offsetParent.

Comment: it is obviously because `style.left` has no any affect on not positioned elements=)

Comment: aha, I see, if I does not set the position property, HTML elements are positioned static by default, static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties.

Comment: So if an element is dispalyed by static mode, the style.left has no meaning, if an element is displayed by no static mode, the style.left equal to offsetLeft, right?

Comment: So if I try to get the left position about an element, I should always try the offsetLeft, because this property is always represent the left distance to offsetParent, and if I want set the left property, I should use style.left and ensure the element is displayed by non-static mode. Because offsetLeft is readonly and left property will affect nothing in static mode.